# C++ calling template method of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have got the following scenario:

one variadic template class which inherits "itself" to resolve the variadic template parameter. The variadic template class has two template methods. Within these methods i want to call the base template class template method. For the set method it seems to work.

```
template<class T, class ... R>
class ValueProvider : ValueProvider<R...>{
    public:

        T value;
        const std::type_info& type = typeid(T);

        ValueProvider()
        {}

        template<class G>
        inline G get(){
            if(this->type.hash_code() == typeid(G).hash_code())
                return this->value;
            else{
                //----- interesting part -----
                return ValueProvider<R...>::get<G>();        /*<- compile ERROR: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token*/
                return ValueProvider<R...>::get();        /*<- compile ERROR: no matching function for call to ‘ValueProvider<int, char>::get()’*/
                return ValueProvider::get<G>();        /*<- runtime ERROR (infinit recursion)*/
            }
        }

        template<class G>
        void set(G p){
            if(this->type.hash_code() == typeid(G).hash_code())
                this->value = p;
            else
                ValueProvider<R...>::set(p);
        }
};

template<class T>
class ValueProvider<T>{
    public:
        T value;
        const std::type_info& type = typeid(T);

        ValueProvider()
        {}

        template<class G>
        inline G get(){
            if(this->type.hash_code() == typeid(G).hash_code())
                return this->value;
            throw "fail";
        }

        template<class G>
        void set(G p){
            if(this->type.hash_code() == typeid(G).hash_code())
                this->value = p;
            else
                throw "fail";
        }
};
```

How can i call the base class's template function?

Comment: Could you use more exact terms. Like "class template" in stead of "class" when it is a class template and not a defined class ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Why are `set` and `get` templated? You literally wrote that their types must be `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual dependent-name issue: as `ValueProvider<R...>` depends on `R`, you must disambiguate that `get` in that scope is a template:

```
return ValueProvider<R...>::template get<G>();
```